# LinkedIn profile API returning 403

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm not a LinkedIn partner - so I got an access token with r_basicprofile scope (and not r_fullprofile which is not available to me).
According to the docs - this api requires either r_basicprofile or r_fullprofile. However, I cannot get any of my calls to go through without returning a 403. Any ideas?

https://api.linkedin.com/v2/me

or (all basic profile fields)
https://api.linkedin.com/v2/people/(id:{profile ID})?projection=(id,firstName,lastName,industryId~)

Thanks,
Mike

Answer (score 0):

If you are not a current LinkedIn Partner, you do not have access to our v2 API just yet! Try making a similar request using our v1 API:

`https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~`

See https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/v1/people/profile-api for more information about the Profile API.

Comment: If that is the case, why is there no mention of this huge restriction on the v2 homepage at https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/guide/v2 ?

Comment: This is indeed incorrect. Although the sentence gets cut off it literally says "We are currently accepting applications to access our Ad Technology, Marketing Analytics and Audience Management APIs. No application is required to access our basic" on that page. It should be perfectly possible to perform the above request without having to be approved. Maybe the API was opened to public since this issue was posted but I'm currently still facing the same problem.

Comment: LinkedIn is currently in the process of releasing the v2 APIs. Follow the LinkedIn Blog for the latest updates (https://engineering.linkedin.com/blog/2018/12/developer-program-updates).